# Typescript add function overload to interface

Tags: typescript

I am aware that it is possible to extend an interface from an other module in TypeScript like this:

```js
declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            readonly foo: string;
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering wether the same thing is possible with functions that already exist on the type that is being augmented.
For example, the express `Request` interface (which has already been modified in the previous example) also contains a member function `header()`. This function has a single `string` parameter. But there is also another overload that takes the Type `set-cookie`. Is it possible to add another overload for that function, e.g. with the Type `Authorization`, kind of like this:

```js
declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            header(name: 'Authorization'): string | undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this example does not work (or this question would be somewhat pointless). Also, I am very much aware that it is currently already possible to call the function `header()` with the argument `'Authorization'`, but it would be a little nicer for developers if VS Code would show them `'Authorization'` in the auto-complete box.

Comment: try `header<T extends  'Authorization'>(name: T): string | undefined;` and please let me know if it helps

Comment: No, unfortunately it did not work.